# Inserting data into SQL using VBA ADODB Objects

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I read data from an Excel sheet into a Collection. The data is successfully read and stored. Then, I try to write the contents of the collection into a SQL table using ADODB objects, but for some reason, it's not working, and I would like to understand why. Here is the important code:

```
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
strSQL = "<table name>"

rst.Open strSQL, Cnxn, adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdTableDirect

For Each row In copyRange.Rows
    For Each cell In row.Cells
        With cell
            tempCol.Add (.Value)
        End With
    Next

    strFind = tempCol.Item(2)
    rst.Find strFind, 0, adSearchForward

    If rst.EOF Then
        MsgBox ("Entry not found, insert new entry")
        rst.AddNew
        rst!Date= tempCol(1)
        rst!UID = tempCol(2)
        rst!Field1= tempCol(3)
        rst!Field2= tempCol(4)
        rst!Field3= tempCol(5)
        rst!Field4= tempCol(6)
        rst!Field5= tempCol(7)
        rst!Field6= tempCol(8)

        rst.Update
    Else
        MsgBox ("Entry found, update existing")
        rst!Fiedl4= tempCol(6)
        rst!Field5= tempCol(7)
        rst!Field6= tempCol(8)
        rst.Update
    End If
```

I get the "Entry not found, insert new entry" message, but nothing is actually written to the SQL table, and I don't understand why?

Comment: Ages since I did anything like this, but I think you need UpdateBatch!

Comment: @JonathanWillcock, is there a better way of doing this? Because that would be awesome...

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but your collection is never cleared and so for the 2nd iteration, it adds the values to `tempCol(9)...`.

Comment: Hi @FunThomas: No, Jonathan was right that I needed updateBatch, but not I'm having issues with the recordSet.Find :( Telling me that arguments are of wrong type, out of range or in conflict when it actually finds a value that has been inserted

Comment: The Find method needs a Criteria parameter in the Form `FieldName = Value`.  You seem only to be passing the value??

Comment: Perfect! Works find now!